# How do i remove the chequred background on Ilustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

How do I get rid of this chequered background? I have tried Ctrl+command+H and is not working, please help?

Answer (score 2):

`View > Hide Transparency Grid`

Or use the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: or "View > Hide Transparency Grid"